# Handling link clicks with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is the best practice for handling links in a Backbone app?

a) Should each view listen to a click event for links rendered by itself?
b) Or should there be a global click event listener attached to, say, document, that intercepts all link clicks and executes Backbone.History.navigate with their href?

I have seen both approaches, is there a preferred one?

Comment: if under 'handle links' you mean navigation between pages - Backbone Router should maintain this, if you mean listen click events - View should listen to events inside its template

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.  But Backbone.Router only handles links (navigates) with '#'.  With regular links (using pushState), you need to intercept a click , point the router to the href and cancel the default action.  All manually, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the application you are trying to write.

What I generally do is, if it's a list of items where the count is greater than 10 and each one of these items have click handlers, I put the click handler on the parent view or document view. If you only need 1 instance of the view with the click handler, then you needn't worry about delegating your events to the document/parent.

Comment: For other actions - sure.  But what about the navigation links around the app, like 'Back', 'Home', etc..?